# ThreadPoolExecutor returning null

Tags: java, threadpool

I have this method:

```
public class NFeRoboServiceImpl implements NFeRoboService {

 private static volatile ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    private ThreadPoolExecutor getExecutor() {
        if (executor == null) {
            synchronized (NFeRoboServiceImpl.class) {
                if (executor == null) {
                    executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                            new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100, true), new RetryRejectedExecutionHandler());
                    Monitor monitor = new Monitor(nFePersistenceService, executor, 3);
                    Thread monitorThread = new Thread(monitor);
                    monitorThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
        return executor;
    }
}
```

The problem is very strange, when i put the cursor above the 'executor' after the new ThreadPoolExecutor, it say's that the object is null, when i select executor and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, it shows me the object created.

I'm having null at thread executor:

```
getExecutor().execute(worker);
```

Comment: Is `executor` a static field? It sounds like this is at least somewhat IDE-specific. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Im using eclipse

Comment: You are **definitely** not using a **valid** version of "double checked locking". See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom for options.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, executor is static. In that case you should define it volatile.
See "double-checking" Answer of [Should I synchronize a static volatile variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697451/should-i-synchronize-a-static-volatile-variable)

And see:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Probably eclipse uses getExecutor, when it tries to determine the value of executor, because of the Bean-Convention. What happens if you rename the implicitly initialising function to something not related to the fieldname?

Comment: ok, sorry should be a comment, since you seem to have problems with the debugger. Nevertheless: multithreaded initialisation with double-checking must be done using volatile.  I extended my answer, please look at the last sentence.

Comment: Tks for the answer, im using private static volatile ThreadPoolExecutor executor; and yes, im having problems while debugging.

Comment: Probably eclipse uses getExecutor, when it tries to determine the value of executor, because of the Bean-Convention. And so the object possibly gets initialized by the debugger call. What happens if you rename the implicitly initializing function to something not related to the fieldname? Did it change the behavior, what does worker do? What do you mean by; I am having a null at. Is there a stacktrace?